# Outputting old form data with Twig

Tags: php, twig, slim

Is there an easier way to output old form data with Twig in this example? Inside this ternary operator, it automatically escapes the `value=""` string which is undesired. I still want the old email value escaped.

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="email"{{ request.post('email') ? (' value="' ~ request.post('email')|e ~ '"')|raw : '' }}>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what `request.post` is, but assuming it behaves like Symfony's `app.request.request.get` (returning null if no such post param exists) you can simply do:

```
<input value="{{ request.post("email") }}" />
```

It'll be the value if it exists, or an empty value if it doesn't. If you are a purist and do not wish to see an empty value attribute, you can do this:

```
<input{% if request.post("email") %} value="{{ request.post("email") }}"{% endif %} />
```

Comment: It's the Slim framework, but I see your point. I guess the best way to do this would be with an if statement then. Thank you.